# PyArray_SimpleNewFromData makes the first entry incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes, eigen

I am converting some Eigen matrices to PyObject's:

```
typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> RMatrix;

static PyObject * myfunc(PyObject * self, PyObject * args)
{
  double scalar;
  RMatrix mat_1;
  RMatrix mat_2;

  // some works

  PyObject * py_scalar = PyFloat_FromDouble(scalar);

  npy_intp size_1[2] = {(npy_intp)mat_1.rows(), (npy_intp)mat_1.cols()};
  PyObject * py_mat_1 = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, size_1, NPY_DOUBLE, mat_1.data());

  npy_intp size_2[2] = {(npy_intp)mat_2.rows(), (npy_intp)mat_2.cols()};
  PyObject * py_mat_2 = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, size_2, NPY_DOUBLE, mat_2.data());

  PyObject * tuple = PyTuple_New(3);
  PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 0, py_scalar);
  PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 1, py_mat_1);
  PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 2, py_mat_2);
  return tuple;
}
```

The problem is, `mat_1(0,0)` in C++ is not the same as `mat_1[0,0]` in Python (the same also happens in `mat_2`), while other entries are fine. It looks to me that the first entries are uninitialized and with unusual values like 2.41e-316. What is the reason?

**Update**: the reason of the issue should be that the memory gets destroyed when exitting the function. Creating a new array (`PyArray_FromAny`) and copying the data (`memcpy`) solved the problem.

Comment: `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()` doesn't own the memory. Who holds it in your code after the return from `myfunc()`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes I think this is the problem. I solved this by creating a new array by `PyArray_FromAny` and `memcpy`.